# Why does my app not sync successfully with firebase

Tags: android, json

Android resource linking failed Output: error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification not found.

Comment: post your build gradle code

Answer (score 1):

please  in build.gradle file add
compile androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1

Answer (score 0):

Its not  firebase problem. In  Build.gradle file add

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```